# parse float to text box

Tags: c#, parsing, textbox

simple question that is evading me at the moment.i need the 2 lines below to parse to float. with those 2 lines i get this:  Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'test.Form1.ore' to 'string'. so i figure parse the text boxes to float as that is what will be passed to the text boxes can anyone show me what i am missing.

```
textBox3.Text = books[0]; // update the first text
textBox4.Text = books[1]; // update the second text
```

I tried this

```
textBox4.Text = float.Parse(books[1]);  //update the second text
```

but it did not work either

adding all code for reference

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

 namespace test
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ore
    {
        public float Titan;
        public float Eperton;
    }
    ore b1 = null;
    ore b2 = null;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        b2 = new ore();
        b1 = new ore();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        float tempFloat;


        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {
            b1.Titan = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }


    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {
            b2.Eperton = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");


    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ore> oreData = new List<ore>();
        oreData.Add(b1);
        oreData.Add(b2);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, oreData);
        fs.Close();
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    List<ore> books = new List<ore>();
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        List<ore> books = (List<ore>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Close();

        if (books.Count > 1)
        {
            textBox3.Text = float.Parse(books[0]).ToString();//update the first text
            textBox4.Text = float.Parse(books[1]).ToString();
            //update the second text
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean "did not work"? Did you get an error message? Did an alien drop from the sky and tell you off?

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"? What part didn't work? Did you get an error? Do you see the wrong value? Did your computer explode?

Comment: im sorry Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'float.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments is error message for the new code i tried

Comment: BTW this Did an alien drop from the sky and tell you off?  was AWESOME

Answer (score 1):

"Parse" means to process a string (text) into a particular value type, such as a float or integer. This is *not* what you need. In fact, you need to do the opposite: get a string representation of some other value.

To assign a non-string value to a textbox, simply call the `ToString()` method.

```
double dbl = 0;
MyTextBox.Text = dbl.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`textBox4.Text` requires that you assign it a string. You're assigning it a float. If you need to display a float *as* a string, just use the `ToString` method.

```
textBox4.Text = float.Parse(books[1]).ToString();
```

Comment: That code is redundant. `float.Parse` accepts a parameter of type `string`, which you immediately convert *back* into a string by calling the `ToString()` method. Just assign the string directly, no parsing or conversion needed.

Comment: @Cody: yeah, the logic confused me too. But the OP didn't say what type `books` was, so I assumed... well I assumed and you know what they say about that.

Comment: okay once again im sorry for confusion i added the entire page of code so it can bee seen. @Cody Gray if i understad you right i will need this :textBox4.Text = books[1].ToString();

Comment: program compiles and runs but i get test.Form1+ore in the text boxes when i click the button to read from my binary file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the contents of the textbox into a number, then you've written the code backwards.

What you have now attempts to assign the return value of the `float.Parse` method to the `Text` property of your textbox. That doesn't work, of course, because the function returns a `float` and the `Text` property expects a `string`.

Instead, to parse the string value contained in `books[1]`, you should write this:

```
float myValue = float.Parse(books[1]));
```

And to convert a `float` to a string that you can display in a textbox, you should write this:

```
textBox4.Text = books[1].ToString();
```

Comment: what i am trying to do is read from a binary file load the contents into a list then display the first variable in that list in text box 1 and so on with all the variables in the list, there will be 9 total once i figure out how to do this .

Comment: updated code as i understand :   if (books.Count > 1)
            {
                float titan = float.Parse(books[0]));
                float eperton = float.Parse(books[1]));
                textBox3.Text = titan.ToString();//update the first text box
                textBox4.Text = eperton.ToString();//update the second text box
                
            } ..... this gives mt the error : Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'test.Form1.ore' to 'string'